# editing input fields together instead of separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Current Scenario :**

Right now I have a form in which you can edit and save each records of input fields. i.e. firstName, lastName, email etc..
I do not get any errors and everything is working fine.

**Requirement :**

Now what I want to save & edit `firstName` and `lastName` input fields together instead is to edit and save `firstName` and `lastName` input field separately.
Right now they are all different input id's.

**Question :**

How can I achieve this by calling the same class for `firstName` and `lastName` if I want to edit them at the same time with a button ?

Is this a way to do it ? Thanks...

**Code :**

```
$("#inputFirstName,#inputLastName,#inputEmailAddress,#inputPassword,#inputZipCode").on('keypress',function(e){
        if(e.which == 13) {
            var field = $(this).attr("id");
            var data = {};
            data['ajax']=true;
            data[$('#'+field).attr('name')]=$('#'+field).val();
            $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: this.form.action,
                    data: data
                })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                if(msg['status']=='fail'){
                    $('#errormsg span').html(msg['msg']);
                    $('#errormsg').show();
                }
                if($('#'+field).attr('name')=='game_user_profile[userinfo][firstName]')  {
                    $('#userfirstname').text($('#'+field).val());
                }
                if($('#'+field).attr('name')=='game_user_profile[userinfo][lastName]')  {
                    $('#userlastname').text($('#'+field).val());
                }
            });
            $('#'+field+'-edit').show();
            $('#'+field+'-save').hide()
            $('#'+field).attr('disabled',true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Its a simple task. create a single button for both `firstname` and `lastname` and on click of that button pass both field data together in an object and do operations as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all. save on every keypress is bad and will exhaust your server.
I recommennd you use onChange or make a submit button

submit button is a better solution.

lets assume that we have this html:

```
<form id="updateForm">
    <input type="text" id="firstN" name="firstName" data-val="Ris" value="Ris">
    .
    .
    .
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="goBtn">
</form>
```

first set a data-val equal to the value
then in your javascript

```
$("#goBtn").click(function(){

    var data = {};
    data["ajax"] = true;
    $("#updateForm input").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var type = $this.attr('type');
        if(type != "button" && $this.val() != $this.attr("data-val"))
            data[$this.attr("name")] = $this.val();
    });

    if(data.length > 0){
             $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: this.form.action,
                    data: data
                })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                if(msg['status']=='fail'){
                    $('#errormsg span').html(msg['msg']);
                    $('#errormsg').show();
                } else {
                    $.each(data, function(index, value){
                        $('updateForm input[name="'+index+'"]').attr("data-val", value);
                    });
                }
                // then do things
            });
    }

});
```

first it checks every input for changes (`data-val` is holding the original value) and it adds it to data if there is any changes at all it calls the ajax and if it was successful it updates the `data-val`s of each changed value else it leave it for another submission